# How can I get edge events via GPIO on Linux without a busy-loop?

Tags: linux, gpio

I'm working an a system with embedded Linux (Kernel 2.6.31).

It is a AT91SAM9G20 chip inside, and some of the Pins are forwarded to the outside.

Now I want to use them as GPIO Inputs.

I read the gpio.txt documentation about using the GPIOs via filesystem, and that works very well 'til here. I connected some switches to the gpio-pins and I can see the result in `/sys/class/gpio/gpioX/value`. But now I'd like to react on a change without busy-waiting in a loop. (i.e echo "Switch1 was pressed").

I guess I need interrupts here, but I couldn't find out how to use them without writing my own kernel driver. I'm relatively new to Linux and C (I normally program in Java), so I'd like to handle the Interrupts via sysfs too. But my problem is, that there is no "edge"-file in my GPIO directory (I guess because this is only since Kernel version 2.6.33+). Is that right? Instead of "edge" I've got a `uevent` file in there, which is not described in `gpio.txt`.

In the gpio.txt documentation there was a Standard Kernel Driver mentioned: "gpio_keys". Is it possible to use this for my problem?

I guess it would be better to work with this driver than allowing a userspace program to manipulate kernel tasks.
I found a lot of codesnippets for writing my own driver, but I wasn't even able to find out which of the 600 `gpio.h` files to include, and how to refer to the library (cross compiler couldn't find the gpio.h file).

Sorry for newbie questions, I hope you could give me some advices.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140117032457/https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Gpio-int-test.c) for an example on how to do that. Basically, the thing you're missing is the usage of the `select` or `poll` system calls.

Comment: even when there is no "edge" file to write whether to liste to rising or falling flanks? I can just use "poll" to get my interrupt?

Comment: okay now i tried the example with poll, but as I expected there is a error, because no "edge" file exists, and exactly after I started the program the prompt says: "poll() GPIO 82 interrupt occured" (even if I hadn't clicked the switch). But after that prompt nothing happens anymore, even when I push the button I connected with GPIO 82 (no prompt about any further interrupts). Is it because the "edge" file? Can I easily create it?

Comment: Link-mosltly answer has now experienced link-rot.

Comment: @ThomasPetazzoni, would you consider updating this answer to be useful standing on its own (such that it's a helpful contribution to the knowledgebase even if links fail)?